# Hovering child triggers hover for parent?

Tags: html, css

I have one parent element (a button in this case), and this parent button has five child buttons. Here is the html for this

```
<div id="C_Btn3" class="AtlasRootButton multiButton1 AtlasCircleButton" style="height: 3rem; width: 3rem; line-height: 3rem;">
    <div class="fa fa-gamepad fa-3x"></div>
    <div class="AtlasButton subButton AtlasCircleButton" style="position: relative; height: 3rem; width: 3rem; line-height: 3rem; display: inline-block; bottom: 8rem; left: -7rem;"></div>
    <div class="AtlasButton subButton AtlasCircleButton" style="position: relative; height: 3rem; width: 3rem; line-height: 3rem; display: inline-block; bottom: 15.5rem; left: -1rem;"></div>
    <div class="AtlasButton subButton AtlasCircleButton" style="position: relative; height: 3rem; width: 3rem; line-height: 3rem; display: inline-block; bottom: 17rem; left: 4.75rem;"></div>
    <div class="AtlasButton subButton AtlasCircleButton" style="position: relative; height: 3rem; width: 3rem; line-height: 3rem; display: inline-block; bottom: 13.25rem; left: 4rem;"></div>
    <div class="AtlasButton subButton AtlasCircleButton" style="position: relative; height: 3rem; width: 3rem; line-height: 3rem; display: inline-block; bottom: 17.75rem; left: -5rem;"></div>
</div>
```

and here is the relevant css

```
.AtlasCircleButton {
    padding: 0.75rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.AtlasMultiCircleButton {
    min-width: 1rem;
    min-height: 1rem;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.AtlasButton {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.AtlasButton:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.AtlasRootButton {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.AtlasRootButton:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.multiButton1 {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}

.multiButton1:hover {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}

.subButton {
    z-index: 99;
}
```

my issue that I cannot figure out for the life of me is when I hover over one of the children it also triggers the hover for the parent and this is not what I want! I'm guessing this is somewhere in the css but I could not find anything from googling this topic, only things about having the hover of the child trying to trigger the parent's hover styles which is complete opposite of what I want.

**EDIT**

I gave the root button its own distinct class and the same issue still persists. One thing I discovered is when I trigger the hover for the subButtons in the chrome dev tools by clicking the hover check box the root button hover doesn't get triggered but not when doing it normally.

Comment: It's `.AtlasButton:hover`.

Comment: yeah you have given you button holder the same class as your buttons

Comment: That answer you marked correct isn't right. It's not about switching classes, but the fact that you are hovering parent every-time you wish to hover it's child as well. You can either take sub-buttons out of parent or comment parent :hover behavior so when hovering it's child it's not linked.

Comment: I made the suggested edit but the issue still persists. See edit above

Answer (score 1):

because your parent div class and child div class is same.Both is atlasbutton.when you give hover to the elements make spesific for example in your case change atlasbutton:hover to subbutton:hover

note:sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Did this and did not change the result